# How to wait for response before going to next action?

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I have a function which is responsible to save data in *strapi cms* which will generate an `id` and with that `id` I want to invoke another function.

The problem is, that once user clicks the button, data is being sent to the cms and without waiting the id to be returned, it proeeds with the other action.

In my case the other action is sending an email, and when I send the email, the `id` is not returned so I get `undefined`.
But once user clicks the second time, id already there and email can be sent successfully.

My goal is to wait until `id` is already `available` and only then send an `email`.

Here is the code where I am saving the data via `apollo-client` and getting the `id`: called `newID`.

```
const [newID, setNewID] = useState<number>();

const [addProject, { loading }] = useMutation(PROJECT_MUTATION, {
  onCompleted(data) {
    setSubmitted(true);
    setNewID(data.createdProject.data.id); // I am getting the id here
  },
  onError() {
    setError(true);
  },
});

useEffect(() => {
  if ( imageUploaded ) {
    addProject({
      variables: {
        title: formData.uploaderMail
      },
  })
    .catch((error) => {
      setError(true);
    })
    .then(() => {
      setSubmitted(true);
     });
   }
  }, [ addProject, formData.uploaderMail]);
```

And here I am trying to send an email with the id that should be returned and saved in `setNewId` setter function.

```
const sendDEmailHandleClick = useCallback(() => {
  if (newID && formData.uploaderMail) {
    sendEmail(
      formData.uploaderMail,
      newID // here on the first click id is undefined
    );
    setEmailError("");
  } else {
    setEmailError("Something went wrong");
  }
}, [ formData.uploaderMail, newID ]);
```

`sendEmail` is just a function which expects to arguments to be sent

```
const sendEmail = async (uploaderMail, id) => {
  const sendEmail = await fetch(
    `/api/req/${uploaderMail}/${id}`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }
  );
};
```

And button responsible for sending the email.

```
<Button
  type="submit"
  onClick={sendDEmailHandleClick}
>
  Send email
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `sendDEmailHandleClick` in id change rather than the click event.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(newID){
    sendDEmailHandleClick()
  }

}, [newID])
```